# Developer jobs directory link in the Stack Overflow page footer

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I just saw the "developer jobs directory" link in the Stack Overflow page footer.

[image: Developer Job Directory - footer link]

Clicking on the link, it is self explanatory. But is there any official post related to the new feature? Or it is for A/B testing?

Comment: It looks like a SEO feature to me; a tree of links to help search engines categorise the job pages better.

Comment: E.g. seaching for "Contract senior developer jobs in London, UK" will draw a direct hit on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/directory/jobs-by-experience-level-job-type-location) so Google can link you directly to the search page with the right filters pre-selected.

Comment: In other words, this isn't really intended for human consumption nor needs to be explained as an official feature.

Answer (score 3):

As Martijn guessed this is for SEO purposes. It's not particularly pretty because it's generally intended for crawlers. There's a possibility that this will eventually evolve into a more comprehensive 'browse jobs' feature. Stay tuned!